# aspx / aspx.vb cannot write to Excel file on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are running an intranet and have aspx / aspx.vb applications that collect data from a form, send it to an e-mail task and add it to an Excel file. Typically it works fine.

We had found in the past that opening the Excel file in Excel would cause the application to be unable to write to the Excel file. The solution was to copy the Excel file to the local PC and open it there. It seems that for some reason the server had to "own" the file, and someone opening it from Excel would disrupt that ownership.

Periodically the Excel file will fill up (97 format / 65535 available rows), and we would need to replace the file with a blank copy. This happens every few years. In order to do that, something had to be done to the IIS server so that the file could be written to by the application. The IT person who used to do this is no longer here and we can't figure out what he did when this was needed. We tried stopping the server before the file was refreshed, and then starting the server but this does seem to have any affect. The web application can't write to the file. It seem to work from the user standpoint but nothing shows up in the file.

Any ideas on what we need to do that we aren't doing? Or perhaps why the server needs to "own" the file in order to write to it?

The code seems simple enough:

```
    Protected Sub btnLogExpedite_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogExpedite.Click
    'Log info 
    '<add name="ExcelConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SchoolMgt.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"/>
    Try
        LogExpedite(Server.MapPath("../expediting/ExpeditingLog.xls"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim objEventLog As New EventLog()
        objEventLog.Source = "Application"
        objEventLog.WriteEntry("Expediting Web App: " & ex.ToString, EventLogEntryType.Error, 1000)
        objEventLog = Nothing
    End Try
```

and

```
    Private Sub LogExpedite(ByVal sFile As String)
    Try
        Dim sDate As Date = Now()

        Dim sSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$](Material,MRPCtlr,MMPPStatus,ReferenceNumber,Quantity,ConfirmedDate,TargetDate,Reason,AdditionalInfo,LoggedBy,DateLogged,TimeLogged) " & _
            "VALUES ('" & EscapeChar(txtMaterialToExpedite.Text) & "','" & EscapeChar(hidMRPCtlr.Value) & "','" & EscapeChar(hidMMPPStatus.Value) & "','" & EscapeChar(txtReferenceNumber.Text) & "','" & EscapeChar(txtQuantity.Text) & "','" & _
            EscapeChar(txtConfirmedDate.Text) & "','" & EscapeChar(txtTargetDate.Text) & "','" & EscapeChar(ddlReasonForExpedite.SelectedValue) & "','" & EscapeChar(txtAdditionalInformation.Text) & "','" & Mid(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"), 5) & "','" & _
            DatePart(DateInterval.Month, sDate) & "/" & DatePart(DateInterval.Day, sDate) & "/" & DatePart(DateInterval.Year, sDate) & "','" & DatePart(DateInterval.Hour, sDate) & ":" & DatePart(DateInterval.Minute, sDate) & ":" & DatePart(DateInterval.Second, sDate) & "')"
        Dim cnExcel As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sFile & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        cnExcel.Open()
        Dim cmExcel As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSQLInsert, cnExcel)
        cmExcel.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cnExcel.Close()
        cnExcel = Nothing
        cmExcel = Nothing
```

Thanks!
Blair

Comment: Why don't you just use a database? This is a really convoluted solution.

Comment: In all likelyhood, the IIS process has no rights to the folder / file and, when Excel starts, it inherits those rights so it fails to open the file (or fails to write it).

Comment: we should use a database, but have limited resources in the IT group to do any development work.

Comment: It is the aspx.vb code that is trying to open a SQL server connection to the Excel file and write to it.

Comment: In that case your IIS process may not have rights to access the path. It's impossible to tell for sure without seeing the server setup.

Comment: Could be an area of investigation, but if it worked before the Excel file was replaced it would seem plausible that it was configured properly prior to that.